# Find Job Status by Job name or id for a hadoop mapreduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm very new to hadoop and have question.
  I'm submitting (or creating) mapreduce jobs using Hadoop Job API v2 (i.e. namespace mapreduce than old one mapred)

I submit MR Jobs based on our own jobs.  We maintain the Hadoop Job Name in this table.
I want to track the submitted jobs for the progress (and so completion) so that we can update our own jobs as complete.
All the Job Status API requires Job object.  Whereas ‘Job Monitoring’ module of ours does not have any job object with it.

Can you please help us with anyway to get Job Status given a Job Name?  We make sure job name are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I google quite a bit only to find below. Is this the way to go? There is no other way in the v2 (*.mapreduce.* and not *.mapred.*) API to get job's status given the JobId?


    `Configuration conf = new Configuration();`
    `JobClient jobClient = new JobClient(new JobConf(conf)); // deprecation WARN`
    `JobID jobID = JobID.forName(jobID);                     // deprecation WARN`
    `RunningJob runningJob = jobClient.getJob(jobID);`
    `Field field = runningJob.getClass().getDeclaredField("status"); // reflection !!!`
    `field.setAccessible(true);`
    `JobStatus jobStatus = (JobStatus) field.get(runningJob);`
 
http://blog.erdemagaoglu.com/post/9407457968/hadoop-mapreduce-job-statistics-a-fraction-of-them